# JayData incorrect behaviour with WebApi v2 Odata during entity update the Patch endpoint get invoked

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, jaydata, asp.net-web-api-odata

While trying to update the entity, JayData triggers the PatchEntity method on the WepAPI backend. I find this as an invalid behaviour as for the UpdateEntity should be invoked.

The add and delete entity functionality works OK. On the backend I have a controller that inherits from EntitySetController<>

```
public class BaseODataController<TService, TEntity, TEntityDto, TIdentityType> : EntitySetController<TEntityDto, TIdentityType>
{
  //.....

        protected override TEntityDto UpdateEntity(TIdentityType key, TEntityDto update)
        {
            // is not getting called
            _service.Update(update);
            return base.UpdateEntity(key, update);
        }

        protected override TEntityDto PatchEntity(TIdentityType key, Delta<TEntityDto> patch)
        {
            // gets called
            return base.PatchEntity(key, patch);
        }


  //.....
}
```

Here is the code that gets called on the clientside:

```
 vm.updateRole = function(r) {
        return $data.initService('/odata/$metadata').then(function (context) {
            r.Name = "NewUpdateRole";
            context.Role.update(r);
            r.entityState = $data.EntityState.Modified;
            context.saveChanges().then(function(result) {
                debugger;
            });

        });
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JayData sends the MERGE or PATCH requests based on the dataServiceVersion property of the odata provider configuration.

```
$data.initService('/odata/$metadata', {dataServiceVersion: '3.0'})
```

2.0 causes MERGE and 3.0 causes PATCH requests to align with the **WCF Data Services OData** implementation.

If this behavior does not meet the **WebAPI OData** requirements, there is a second customization option to determine the kind of the request:

```
$data.initService('/odata/$metadata', {UpdateMethod: 'PATCH'})
```

You can make a try to modify the `PATCH` to `UPDATE` HTTP Verb